# Node.js design pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I would like to attempt to build a larger, more modular node.js application than my previous attempts.  I am stuck on design patterns as it appears there are way too many ways to accomplish the same thing, and I am lost in the blog FUD around how to accomplish this.  I have worked mainly in MVC frameworks where a global app variable is passed around, and I am wondering if this concept is useful in node.  For example:

./index.js

```
var app = {};
var api = require('api'); // Api server module
var db = require('db'); // db client

var dbh = db.connect(); // connect to db
app['dbh'] = dbh;

api.start(app);
```

./api.js

```
var API = exports;

API.start = function(app, callback) {
  // do api server stuff
  app['dbh'].execute(... function (err, results){
    console.log('foo');
  });
}
```

Is this idea of assigning all functions, configuration data, and variables to an app object a reasonable approach?

Comment: Node has modules as a fundamental part of how it works so usually you would just put a set of methods in a single module and then use the module handle as your natural object container for them.  I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve by creating additional containers outside of the modules themselves.  You can also create modules that do nothing but load other modules and combine their interfaces into a larger module interface.  If you're looking for something beyond what modules offer, then I'd suggest you describe your needs that aren't served by modules.

Comment: IMO, module interfaces should be designed so they can be directly consumed as their module interface so you usually don't need to repackage them into a new interface in some other object.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am only trying to make the code consuming the modules simpler.  The difference between passing all the module variables into a function vs. passing a single app variable.  This would allow me to set and remove functions in app at will and change the code only in the functions consuming the app variable instead of refactoring the function itself.

Comment: As I said, you can make a module that combines the interfaces from several other modules and exports that as its interface (so you could do that with an `app` module).  But, you haven't described anything whose needs would be met just fine with the module architecture used that way so it's hard to know what else to say.  You mention a `global` app variable.  There generally is not a reason to use node.js that way - it's generally more flexible to just put things in a shared module and `require()` in the module anywhere you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know how to pass some objects between Node modules. Below is what I do in this case:

Your main module that contains the `app` object that we'll pass around:

```
// index.js
// this module immediately invokes itself and requires our other modules
module.exports = (function () {
    'use strict';

    // this is the main object I want to use in other modules
    var app = {
        version: '1.0.0'
    };

    // just requiring and invoking module2 with the app argument
    require('./module2')(app);

    // now, I'll set a reference to module3 bec. 
    // I'll also need module3 in module4 below
    var module3 = require('./module3')(app);

    // and here I invoke module4 with 2 arguments this time.
    require('./module4')(app, module3);
    // so on...

    return app;

}());
```

Now in your secondary modules, you can use the passed object(s):

```
// module2.js and/or module3.js
// notice that the module is invoked with the app object.
module.exports = function (app) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(app.version);
    return {
        message: 'Hi there!'
    };
};

// module4.js
// notice that this module is invoked with 2 arguments this time.
module.exports = function (app, module3) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(app.version); // '1.0.0'
    console.log(module3.message); // Hi there!
};
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: That does indeed, I had no idea you could pass arguments to required modules.  Is it a good pattern to define all the required modules the entire application will need in the index.js file such as you did and only use that instance by passing it to other modules?

Comment: You don't have to require all the modules the application needs. You'd do this when a module is dependent on another. If a module conditionally needs another module, I would simply pass it via a method. A complete application would require you to make lots of other design decisions on the way; which is not possible to cover here in a post.

Comment: @MichaelAndrews - one practical use of modules in node.js and a generally good design pattern is to write your code in a way that you can reuse your modules in other projects without having to change them.  That means you should create each module as a stand-alone entity that does something useful on its own.  It is free to `require()` in other modules that it needs to do its job (that caller need not be aware of what modules it uses internally).

Comment: @MichaelAndrews -   So, this should generally be your primary goal.  As such, you rarely want to create another module that only loads a whole bunch of other modules because that isn't really doing much for you.  It is unlikely that you have multiple modules that all need to `require()` in the exact same set of other modules and you really don't want to be reworking the interfacing on every one of your modules as that doesn't really move the ball forward either.  Just get used to `require()` in what any given module needs.

Comment: Once more, this answer only suggests an approach to what OP calls "passing around a global app variable".

Comment: I guess what is driving this question is the lack of clear methods for how to structure an application, and in this case I am not writing just a web application.  My application is a fairly complex system that will use user created plugins inside my framework to possibly consume data from inputting clients, or make calls to remote systems to gather information.  After the plugin parses the information it sticks it into db and the web interface (the smallest part of the app really) would display information about the data.

Comment: I sat down and started writing this app like I had learned while reading how-to books and such and it just feels like the bare bones nodejs approach to structuring apps is far too open ended and really does not help you scale a code base.  I have been looking at Architect by C9 as a possible framework on top of node to build this application, but I thought maybe I could find a design paradigm that did not require a third party framework to keep my application from becoming a pile of modules flying all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a minor adjustment for it to work:

```
// api.js
module.exports.start = function(app, callback) {
  // do api server stuff
  app['dbh'].execute(... function (err, results){
    console.log('foo');
  });
}
```